# Not able to set Js variable in img src

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to set some html content created in javascript in specific div.

I am trying below code -

```
var imgPath = data.destPath+data.fileName;
console.log(imgPath);    //  assets/users/Digvj_2_1480977246_tmp.png

var str = '<img src="{{asset('+imgPath+')}}" width="500" id="image_cropbox"><br><span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 13px"><small>Select The Required Area To Crop Image.</small></span>';
console.log(str);      // src= "http://localhost:8000/+imgPath+"

$('#user_profile_img').html(str);
```

In the second log I am trying, Its directly printing the variable name instead of value.

Can't Identify what I am missing here.

Comment: Some content missed in the post --

var str = $('<img src="{{asset('+imgPath+')}}" width="500" id="image_cropbox"><br><span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 13px"><small>Select The Required Area To Crop Image.</small></span>');

Comment: Edit the post instead of posting in the comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade generates the view before the response reaches the client which is when your javascript is executing.  You're trying to use a variable you're defining in javascript as a blade variable.  Update it like this:

```
var imgPath = data.destPath+data.fileName;
console.log(imgPath);    //  assets/users/Digvj_2_1480977246_tmp.png

var str = '<img src="{{asset("")}}'+imgPath+'" width="500" id="image_cropbox"><br><span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 13px"><small>Select The Required Area To Crop Image.</small></span>';
console.log(str);      // src= "http://localhost:8000/+imgPath+"

$('#user_profile_img').html(str);
```

This will generate `http://localhost:8000/` from `{{asset("")}}` and then when the browser loads it will append your js variable to the url.